# Author and time matching regex

Tags: java, regex

I would to use a regex in my Java program to recognize some feature of my strings.
I've this type of string:

> `-Author- has wrote (-hh-:-mm-)

So, for example, I've a string with:

> Cecco has wrote (15:12)

and i've to extract author, hh and mm fields. Obviously I've some restriction to consider:

- hh and mm must be numbers
- author hasn't any restrictions
- I've to consider space between "has wrote" and (

How can I can use regex?

EDIT: I attach my snippet:

```
String mRegex = "(\\s)+ has wrote \\((\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)\\)";
Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile(mRegex);

String[] str = {
    "Cecco CQ has wrote (14:55)", //OK (matched)
    "yesterday you has wrote that I'm crazy", //NO (different text)
    "Simon has wrote (yesterday)", // NO (yesterday isn't numbers)
    "John has wrote (22:32)", //OK
    "James has wrote(22:11)", //NO (missed space between has wrote and ()
    "Tommy has wrote (xx:ss)" //NO (xx and ss aren't numbers)
};

for(String s : str) {
    Matcher mMatcher = mPattern.matcher(s);
    while (mMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(mMatcher.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: "has wrote"? You'll want to drop the "has" - added benefit: "You" and "I" will also work besides actual names.

Comment: "_author hasn't any restrictions_" that's a bad practice: you should at least forbid newline characters in a name, or empty string.

Comment: @LarsTech Well, not everything is done through Google (think of the lateral "Related" links on Stack Overflow). If it's about _other_ edits, then it may need to be discussed case by case; an example could be titles with a length smaller than the now minimum allowed (15 chars), which prevent *any* edit to be made on the body of the question until the title is back to 15 chars minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

homework?

Something like:

```
(.+) has wrote \((\d\d):(\d\d)\)
```

Should do the trick

- `()` - mark groups to capture (there are three in the above)
- `.+` - any chars (you said no restrictions)
- `\d` - any digit
- `\(\)` escape the parens as literals instead of a capturing group

use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+) has wrote \\((\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)\\)");

Matcher m = p.matcher("Gareth has wrote (12:00)");

if( m.matches()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

To cope with an optional (HH:mm) at the end you need to start to use some dark regex voodoo:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+) has wrote\\s?(?:\\((\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)\\))?");

Matcher m = p.matcher("Gareth has wrote (12:00)");

if( m.matches()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}

m = p.matcher("Gareth has wrote");
if( m.matches()){       
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    // m.group(2) == null since it didn't match anything
}
```

The new unescaped pattern:

```
(.+) has wrote\s?(?:\((\d\d):(\d\d)\))?
```

- `\s?` optionally match a space (there might not be a space at the end if there isn't a (HH:mm) group
- `(?: ... )` is a none capturing group, i.e. allows use to put `?` after it to make is optional

I think @codinghorror has [something to say about regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: Thanks very much. But if I've this situation: "Gareth has wrote" without () parameters but with endline, how I modify my pattern string?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to figure out regular expressions is to use a testing tool before coding.
I use an eclipse plugin from http://www.brosinski.com/regex/

Using this I came up with the following result:

```
([a-zA-Z]*) has wrote \((\d\d):(\d\d)\)
Cecco has wrote (15:12)

Found 1 match(es):

start=0, end=23
Group(0) = Cecco has wrote (15:12)
Group(1) = Cecco
Group(2) = 15
Group(3) = 12
```

An excellent turorial on regular expression syntax can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, just in case you didn't know, `Matcher` has a nice function that can draw out specific groups, or parts of the pattern enclosed by (), [`Matcher.group(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29). Like if I wanted to match for a number between two semicolons like:

**:22:**

I could use the regex `":(\\d+):"` to match one or more digits between two semicolons, and then I can fetch specifically the digits with:

`Matcher.group(1)`

And then its just a matter of parsing the String into an int. As a note, group numbering starts at **1**. group(0) is the **whole match**, so Matcher.group(0) for the previous example would return :22:

For your case, I think the regex bits you need to consider are

- `"[A-Za-z]"` for alphabet characters (you could probably also safely use `"\\w"`, which matchers alphabet characters, as well as numbers and _).
- `"\\d"` for digits (1,2,3...)
- `"+"` for indicating you want one or more of the previous character or group.